# Beam ParquetIO.read(SCHEMA) not using specified schema instead using schema from file | Read failing after schema change

Tags: java, apache-beam, avro, apache-beam-io

Reading from parquet file is failing with following exception

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline$PipelineExecutionException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner$DirectPipelineResult.waitUntilFinish(DirectRunner.java:371)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner$DirectPipelineResult.waitUntilFinish(DirectRunner.java:339)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner.run(DirectRunner.java:219)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner.run(DirectRunner.java:67)
```

I'm trying to read a parquet file in Apache beam using following code snippet

```
String path = "pathToFile";
Schema schema = ReflectData.get().getSchema(EntityClass.class)

PCollection<GenericRecord> records = pipeline.apply("read a file", ParquetIO.read(schema).from(path));

pipeline.run().waitUntilFinish();
```

The above code is failing to read the after adding new fields to the java class.

Previous java class:

```
@With
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@ParametersAreNonnullByDefault
@DefaultSchema(JavaBeanSchema.class)
public class EntityClass {
    
    private String firstName;
    
    private String middleName;
    
}
```

Unable to read after making this change to the java class

```
@With
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@ParametersAreNonnullByDefault
@DefaultSchema(JavaBeanSchema.class)
public class EntityClass {

    private String firstName;

    private String middleName;

    @Nullable
    @org.apache.avro.reflect.Nullable
    private String lastName;
}
```

The schema generated from reflection seems to be fine.

```
{
    "type": "record",
    "name": "EntityClass",
    "namespace": "com.test.entityclass",
    "fields": [{
        "name": "firstName",
        "type": "string"
    }, {
        "name": "middleName",
        "type": "string"
    }, {
        "name": "lastName",
        "type": ["null", "string"],
        "default": null
    }]
}
```

Unable to figure out the reason for failure.